# Json Array pulling data by id

Tags: python, arrays, json

Okay, so I'm working on a small app for league of legends and I'm attempting to use their api to pull in a players data. I want to display their top 3 played champions and tell them a bit of information about them. I can do most of this fine but I'm struggling to pull the champions name by the ID. I have a json array file which looks like this. Ill only include a few of them because its rather long for each champion.

```
[
  {
    "id": "aatrox",
    "key": "266",
    "name": "Aatrox",
    "title": "the Darkin Blade",
    "tags": [
      "Fighter",
      "Tank"
    ],
    "stats": {
      "hp": 580,
      "hpperlevel": 85,
      "mp": 100,
      "mpperlevel": 0,
      "movespeed": 345,
      "armor": 24.384,
      "armorperlevel": 3.8,
      "spellblock": 32.1,
      "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
      "attackrange": 150,
      "hpregen": 6.59,
      "hpregenperlevel": 0.5,
      "mpregen": 0,
      "mpregenperlevel": 0,
      "crit": 0,
      "critperlevel": 0,
      "attackdamage": 60.376,
      "attackdamageperlevel": 3.2,
      "attackspeedoffset": -0.04,
      "attackspeedperlevel": 3
    },
    "icon": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png",
    "sprite": {
      "url": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/sprite/champion0.png",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "description": "Aatrox is a legendary warrior, one of only five that remain of an ancient race known as the Darkin. He wields his massive blade with grace and poise, slicing through legions in a style that is hypnotic to behold. With each foe felled, Aatrox's seemingly..."
  },
  {
    "id": "ahri",
    "key": "103",
    "name": "Ahri",
    "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox",
    "tags": [
      "Mage",
      "Assassin"
    ],
    "stats": {
      "hp": 514.4,
      "hpperlevel": 80,
      "mp": 334,
      "mpperlevel": 50,
      "movespeed": 330,
      "armor": 20.88,
      "armorperlevel": 3.5,
      "spellblock": 30,
      "spellblockperlevel": 0.5,
      "attackrange": 550,
      "hpregen": 6.508,
      "hpregenperlevel": 0.6,
      "mpregen": 6,
      "mpregenperlevel": 0.8,
      "crit": 0,
      "critperlevel": 0,
      "attackdamage": 53.04,
      "attackdamageperlevel": 3,
      "attackspeedoffset": -0.065,
      "attackspeedperlevel": 2
    },
    "icon": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/champion/Ahri.png",
    "sprite": {
      "url": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/sprite/champion0.png",
      "x": 48,
      "y": 0
    },
    "description": "Unlike other foxes that roamed the woods of southern Ionia, Ahri had always felt a strange connection to the magical world around her; a connection that was somehow incomplete. Deep inside, she felt the skin she had been born into was an ill fit for her..."
  },
  {
    "id": "akali",
    "key": "84",
    "name": "Akali",
    "title": "the Fist of Shadow",
    "tags": [
      "Assassin"
    ],
    "stats": {
      "hp": 587.8,
      "hpperlevel": 85,
      "mp": 200,
      "mpperlevel": 0,
      "movespeed": 350,
      "armor": 26.38,
      "armorperlevel": 3.5,
      "spellblock": 32.1,
      "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
      "attackrange": 125,
      "hpregen": 8.342,
      "hpregenperlevel": 0.65,
      "mpregen": 50,
      "mpregenperlevel": 0,
      "crit": 0,
      "critperlevel": 0,
      "attackdamage": 58.376,
      "attackdamageperlevel": 3.2,
      "attackspeedoffset": -0.1,
      "attackspeedperlevel": 3.1
    },
    "icon": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/champion/Akali.png",
    "sprite": {
      "url": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/sprite/champion0.png",
      "x": 96,
      "y": 0
    },
    "description": "There exists an ancient order originating in the Ionian Isles dedicated to the preservation of balance. Order, chaos, light, darkness -- all things must exist in perfect harmony for such is the way of the universe. This order is known as the Kinkou and..."
  },
  {
    "id": "alistar",
    "key": "12",
    "name": "Alistar",
    "title": "the Minotaur",
    "tags": [
      "Tank",
      "Support"
    ],
    "stats": {
      "hp": 613.36,
      "hpperlevel": 106,
      "mp": 278.84,
      "mpperlevel": 38,
      "movespeed": 330,
      "armor": 24.38,
      "armorperlevel": 3.5,
      "spellblock": 32.1,
      "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
      "attackrange": 125,
      "hpregen": 8.678,
      "hpregenperlevel": 0.85,
      "mpregen": 8.5,
      "mpregenperlevel": 0.8,
      "crit": 0,
      "critperlevel": 0,
      "attackdamage": 61.1116,
      "attackdamageperlevel": 3.62,
      "attackspeedoffset": 0,
      "attackspeedperlevel": 2.125
    },
    "icon": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/champion/Alistar.png",
    "sprite": {
      "url": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.14.1/img/sprite/champion0.png",
      "x": 144,
      "y": 0
    },
    "description": "As the mightiest warrior to ever emerge from the Minotaur tribes of the Great Barrier, Alistar defended his tribe from Valoran's many dangers; that is, until the coming of the Noxian army. Alistar was lured from his village by the machinations of Keiran..."
  },
```

I can pull the ID of the players 3 favorite champions via the API but I need to use that id to pull the champions name from the Json. So for instance if the players favorite champions id is 266 I need something that will search the json for a key that equals 266 and then return the json object so that i can pull the name from that. I understand what is supposed to happen but have been unable to come up with working code to do this.

Comment: I didn't realize the formatting would be that bad on the copy paste.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z6R1X3g8 If you wanna see a more readable version of the json

Comment: [Markdown is available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to you as a poster.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have your JSON stringified:

```
import json

def find_name(player_key, data):
    matches = [player['name'] for player in data if player.get('key') == player_key]
    return matches[0] if matches else None

json_response = '....'
data = json.loads(json_response)
player_name = find_name(266, data)
```